# Batch Combining CDG and MP3 files

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to combine a load of CDG and MP3 files and convert them into MP4. Using FFMPEG

This is the command I'm using

for %%1 in (**.cdg) do for %%2 in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%%1" -i "%%2" -b:v 1M "%%~n1.mp4"

It almost works, but its using the same cdg file for every mp3. How can I make it go to the next one each time?

Comment: I should point out theres not 2 ** before the .cdg, only 1 it was the only way to stop it being in italics

Comment: I've tidied it up a bit with 

for %%1 in (**.**) do ffmpeg -i "%%~n1.cdg" -i "%%~n1.mp3" -y "%%~n1.mp4" 

this works, but for some reason encodes it 3 or 4 times per video?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.